# What are the prerequisites of Dynamical systems?

Tags: dynamical-systems

I'm really interested in learning dynamical systems (to be more specific, I want to understand things like Lorentz Attractors, the Mandelbrot set, the logistic map and fractal geometry)
I have no acquaintance with advanced mathematics (recently finished high school), and I want to know the list of prerequisites for learning the dynamical systems and if you know some books or websites that I can get help from please share them with me. Thank you.

Comment: An undergraduate math major curriculum should be enough. To get you started, a couple years of calculus, a differential equations course, and a topology course are a pretty important basis.

Comment: Certainly you will need to know the main ideas of calculus. You could get a copy of the book Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos by Strogatz, dive in, and backtrack to fill in any missing knowledge that you need.